# Can a man go to the mikva on shabbos and yom tov?

Tags: shabbat, mikvah-ritual-bath, showering-bathing

Can a man go to the mikva on shabbos and yom tov ?

What are the issues involved ? What about a warm mikva ?

Comment: why was this downvoted ? seems like a perfectly good question to me

Comment: Are you serious? One line with no explanation is a perfectly good question? Maybe try including the content of the question in the body of the post. Maybe explain why a man might want to go to the mikva (there could be multiple reasons). Maybe explain why you think temperature might matter that you choose to mention it. Can you think of no way this post could be improved?? I'm not saying this is the worst post ever but you can't honestly think it's a perfectly good one. It _looks_ like an incredibly lazy one to everyone else.

Comment: https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/mikvah-on-shabbos http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/826475/rabbi-moshe-weinberger/the-halachos-of-a-hot-mikveh-on-shabbos-and-yom-tov-for-men-2-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He can. See [O.C. 326:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=322). It's unclear if one may use very hot water, though, but lukewarm is fine. He should be careful not to squeeze (e.g. water out of the hair.) See MB commentary #24 for details.